# How to dump $form in twig template of custom form?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I am trying to debug $form values on twig template, created for rendering user edit form in my own way but when I am trying to use `{{ dump(form) }}` or `{{ dump($form) }}` browser hangs and then system.

I have already enabled debug mode and disabled caching using this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914)

Could anyone help me with the way to print form values on twig template of mine.

Comment: First do you have https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper enabled ?

Comment: As @berramou said check that you have that module. A side note, render arrays have circular references that causes Drupal to crash when you dump huge render arrays. Try to inspect your $form on the template by using `{{ devel_breakpoint(form) }}` also you could try dumping only the elements you want to inspect `{{ dump(form.element) }}`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks to both of you